# Windows 8 Button [c#]

Tags: c#, windows-8

Каким образом можно реализовать кнопку как в Win8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос то требуется что бы контролы на форме выглядели в стиле Metro но целевая ОС не Win8.

Так вот, к примеру в Win7 "из-коробки" такое сделать нельзя если не пользоваться сторонними библиотеками. Вот к примеру тут можно найти то что нужно [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx)

Comment: Именно это я и имел ввиду. 

Но вот только вопрос: не засорит ли оно Visual Studio ?
А то я помню скачал какое-то расширение и оно изменило внутренности Visual Studio, после чего работать в ней было не удобно до переустановки.